# sub query in inner join containing another sub query

Tags: mysql

I have written a query which joins 3 tables where i need to inner join 2 tables and then inner join the whole result set with another join.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT  R.ID,
        R.Title,
        R.Requirement_Text,
        R.Req_Owner,
        D.desname,
        D.team,
        D.stage,
        D.comm 
FROM Req R 
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  d1.ID AS 'id',
                    d1.designername AS 'desname',
                    d1.teamname AS 'team',
                    s.stage AS 'stage',
                    s.comments As 'comm' 
            FROM descomments d1 
                    LEFT JOIN stagecomments s ON d1.ID = s.ID 
                                                 AND d1.designername = s.designername
        ) D ON R.ID = D.id
WHERE R.ProjectID = 'STE 11.2' 
ORDER BY R.Priority
```

But i am getting following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT d1.ID AS 'id',d1.designername AS 'desname',d1.teamname A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 'descomments' after the first left join.. you're actually joining to D, which is the result of your sub-join..

```
SELECT 
  R.ID,
  R.Title,
  R.Requirement_Text,
  R.Req_Owner,
  D.designername,
  D.teamname,
  s.stage,
  s.comments 
FROM Req R LEFT JOIN descomments D ON R.ID=D.id
LEFT JOIN stagecomments s ON D.ID=s.ID AND D.designername=s.designername
WHERE 
  R.ProjectID='STE 11.2' 
ORDER BY R.Priority
```

Comment: Ahh.. what if you remove the quotes around the aliases? So change: AS 'desname' to AS desname

Comment: String query1="SELECT R.ID,R.Title,R.Requirement_Text,R.Req_Owner,D.desname,D.team,D.stage,D.comm,R.PD_Date,R.EXE_GO,R.Est_Delivery FROM Requirements AS R LEFT JOIN (SELECT d1.ID AS id,d1.designername AS desname,d1.teamname AS team,s.stage AS stage,s.comments AS comm FROM descomments AS d1 LEFT JOIN stagecomments AS s ON d1.ID=s.ID AND d1.designername=s.designername) AS D ON R.ID=D.id WHERE R.ProjectID='STE 11.2' ORDER BY R.Priority";

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT d1.ID AS id,d1.designername AS desname,d1.teamname AS te

Comment: what mysql version are you using? Do you get the same error running the query manually againse the database i.e. not through jdbc?

Comment: mysql version number : 4.0.13-standard-log

Comment: You are using an outdated version of MySQL. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subqueries.html: "With MySQL versions prior to 4.1, it was necessary to work around or avoid the use of subqueries. In many cases, subqueries can successfully be rewritten using joins and other methods."

Comment: same error message? or is it because I forgot to change the column names from the aliases back to their real names? doh! (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the solution, but doesn't MySql use backticks ` and not '?

Like this:

```
SELECT  R.ID,
        R.Title,
        R.Requirement_Text,
        R.Req_Owner,
        D.desname,
        D.team,
        D.stage,
        D.comm 
FROM Req R 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  d1.ID AS `id`,
                    d1.designername AS `desname`,
                    d1.teamname AS `team`,
                    s.stage AS `stage`,
                    s.comments As `comm` 
            FROM descomments d1 
                    LEFT JOIN stagecomments s ON d1.ID = s.ID 
                                                 AND d1.designername = s.designername
        ) D ON R.ID = D.id
WHERE R.ProjectID = 'STE 11.2' 
ORDER BY R.Priority
```

Comment: even if i remove them i am getting errorcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT d1.ID AS id,d1.designername AS desname,d1.teamname AS te

Comment: I meant to replace all ' with `.

Comment: same error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT d1.ID AS `id`,d1.designername AS `desname`,d1.teamname A

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly stripped out the Java string delimiters and concatenation characters that appear within it, your query reads as follows:

```
SELECT
    R.ID,
    R.Title,
    R.Requirement_Text,
    R.Req_Owner,
    D.desname,
    D.team,
    D.stage,
    D.comm
FROM
    Req R
    LEFT JOIN descomments ON
        (
            SELECT
                d1.ID AS 'id',
                d1.designername AS 'desname',
                d1.teamname AS 'team',
                s.stage AS 'stage',
                s.comments As 'comm'
            FROM
               descomments d1
               LEFT JOIN stagecomments s ON
                   d1.ID = s.ID AND
                   d1.designername = s.designername
        ) D ON R.ID = D.id
WHERE
    R.ProjectID = 'STE 11.2'
ORDER BY
    R.Priority
```

The `descomments ON` bit after the `LEFT JOIN` is erroneous. Try the following:

```
SELECT
    R.ID,
    R.Title,
    R.Requirement_Text,
    R.Req_Owner,
    D.desname,
    D.team,
    D.stage,
    D.comm
FROM
    Req AS R
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            d1.ID AS 'id',
            d1.designername AS 'desname',
            d1.teamname AS 'team',
            s.stage AS 'stage',
            s.comments AS 'comm'
        FROM
           descomments AS d1
           LEFT JOIN stagecomments AS s ON
               d1.ID = s.ID AND
               d1.designername = s.designername
    ) AS D ON R.ID = D.id
WHERE
    R.ProjectID = 'STE 11.2'
ORDER BY
    R.Priority
```

Comment: problem is not with query but with MySQL version

Answer (score 0):

Starting with StevieG's rewritten query, the values from stageComments are never used in the query - so it appears to be redundant - but will slow down the query significantly; the following should give the desired results much quicker:

```
SELECT 
  R.ID,
  R.Title,
  R.Requirement_Text,
  R.Req_Owner,
  D.desname,
  D.team,
  D.stage,
  D.comm 
FROM Req R LEFT JOIN descomments D ON R.ID=D.id
WHERE 
  R.ProjectID='STE 11.2' 
ORDER BY R.Priority;
```